# Infinite Loop React Table

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-hooks, infinite-loop

I have a snippet that simulates a scenario that is causing an infinite loop in a Child component:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import "./styles.css";

    const data = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

    //New component with some other stuffs
    function Detail({row}) {
      console.log('in');
      return (<span>You selected {row}</span>)
    }

    export default function App() {
      const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
      const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState();

      useEffect(() => { 
        if (rows.length === 0) {
          //get data from service...
          setRows(data);
        }
      }, [rows]);

      return (
        <>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>
                    Title
                  </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {
                data.map(row => (
                  <tr key={row}>
                    <td>
                    <button type="button" onClick={()=> { setSelectedRow(row)}}> {row} </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                ))
              }
            </tbody>
          </table>
          {selectedRow && (<Detail row={selectedRow}/>)}
        </>
      );
    }
```

[image: Code Sanbox output]

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-rain-u9y2o?file=/src/App.js)

Codesandbox shows just a couple of warnings, but what's happening in my application is that the child component is being rendered infinite times.

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share the link for codesandbox ?

Comment: If data is empty array during setRows(data) that would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Hello @SarunUK I have added it to the original post. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, @windowsill In my original code, I have that validation. I didn't add it in the example because it is not the case.

Comment: Why infinite loop? At first the array is empty so the `setRows` is called. But after that because the array is no longer empty it doesn't get called again.

Comment: Your sandbox has no infinite loop?

Comment: It doesn't @windowsill . My bad guess is that CodeSandBox shows a warning instead. In fact, my original code works fine, but the browser eats up the pc memory after a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in the initial post, I didn't include all the details of the issue. The error was located inside the child Component. I call my API to get some detailed data. Overall, the issue was related to the @windowsill comment, my service was fetching an empty array.
I haven't understood very well the reason for that infinite behavior when using useEffect but I solved it.

[image]

Another thing I don't understand, Why I need to add a second argument (props in my case) to useEffect.

Comment: You must add all dependencies of your effect in the dependency array (that second argument). In this case, `props` is a dependency of this effect because it calls fetchTrace, which relies on props.

However, this isn't great because you probably don't actually want to fetch data every time the props are updated, instead change the dependency to `props.alert.id`.

Comment: Assuming props.alert.id is a value type.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @windowsill .